# Nodejs Readable streams, parsing binary data, preserving order

Tags: node.js, parsing, streaming, readable

Using latest nodejs...

Got a binary coming from mongodb (field within a document).  Means I will be processing multiple binary payloads concurrently.  Data is a media file (h264) made up of slices (nal units).  Each slice is delimited.

Using a readable stream from fs if I act on "data" events is the order of the data chunks preserved?  Can I be guaranteed to process the "data" in order?  (See the origin in the path part of the "this" scope in each call)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order that data is written to a stream is guaranteed to be the same order that it is read with. When writing to a stream, the data is either written or queued, order does not change. This is from the Node.js source:

```
function writeOrBuffer(stream, state, chunk, encoding, cb) {
  chunk = decodeChunk(state, chunk, encoding);
  if (util.isBuffer(chunk))
    encoding = 'buffer';
  var len = state.objectMode ? 1 : chunk.length;

  state.length += len;

  var ret = state.length < state.highWaterMark;
  state.needDrain = !ret;

  if (state.writing || state.corked)
    state.buffer.push(new WriteReq(chunk, encoding, cb));
  else
    doWrite(stream, state, false, len, chunk, encoding, cb);

  return ret;
}
```

This is also how data events are fired:

```
// if we want the data now, just emit it.
if (state.flowing && state.length === 0 && !state.sync) {
  stream.emit('data', chunk);
  stream.read(0);
}
```

The data event won't fire for a chunk unless there is no queued data, which means you will get the data in the order that it was passed in as.