# Node.js `Stream` and chunk order

Tags: node.js, stream

Are Node.js `stream`s order preserving up to and including the `'data'` events? I believe they are, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341097/does-node-js-stream-transform-maintain-the-order-of-the-chunks) also seems to suggest at least that the `pipe` methods are sequential.

I want chunk order to be preserved so that I can call a function that operates on each chunk before the stream ends, i.e., while one part of the stream is being read, I want the buffered data chunk to be processed by a function in the `'data'` event.

However, when I run the following code, where I've used `Math.random` and `setTimeout` to test specifically if the events happen in order:

```
fs.createReadStream(filePath, { encoding: 'ascii' })
  .pipe(streamToEntry)
  .on('data', (chunk) => {
    setTimeout(() => { 
      console.log(chunk); 
    }, Math.random() * 1000)
  });
```

data chunks can be logged in an out-of-order fashion.

Is this because of `setTimeout()` or because the `'data'` event is not necessarily called sequentially? i.e., should ordered processing only happen in the `pipe` methods, or can I process the data at the end sequentially?

Comment: Try it without setTimeout and see. Remember, setTimeout doesn't guarantee when the callback will run; it might occur either side of your 1000 period. Add to that you're using a random delay for each chunk, and they're bound to be out of order

Comment: @sofcal The `Math.random` is there to test if they will be out of order - this is certainly not for any particular feature :) Without `setTimeout`, it appears to work. But that might be because `console.log` is not intensive. Perhaps with an intensive method it would be out of order on an infrequent basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `data` events are guaranteed to be emitted in order. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18832424/865038) for some additional details and some snippets from node's source code, which shows that indeed you will get your `data` events in order.

The problem appears when you add asynchronous code in your `data` callback (`setTimeout` is an example of async code). In this situation, your `data` callbacks are not guaranteed to finish processing in the order they were called.

What you need to do is ensure that by the time your `data` callback returns, you have fully processed your data. In other words your callback code needs to be sync code.

```
fs.createReadStream(filePath, { encoding: 'ascii' })
  .pipe(streamToEntry)
  .on('data', (chunk) => {
      // only synchronous code here
      console.log(chunk); 
  });
```

To make the question code work, `async`/`await` can be used:

```
fs.createReadStream(filePath, { encoding: 'ascii' })
  .pipe(streamToEntry)
  .on('data', async (chunk) => {
      // only synchronous code here
      await setTimeout(() => console.log(chunk), Math.random() * 1000); 
  });
```